# Matlab coder error "for loop index expressions.." how to modify code?

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-coder

On Matlab coder I get the error "FOR loop index expressions of unknown size are only supported if they are of the form A:B or A:B:C" whenever I use for indexing a vector in a for loop, example:

```
for e=s:-1:1
for l=1:s
    for k=1:b       
    E=find(sum(B(:,l,:))==k)';
    coder.varsize('E', [1,70],[0,1]);
        for j=E
            coder.varsize('i', [1,70],[0,1]);
            for i=E
                if isequal(B(:,e,i),B(:,e,j)) %for k=1 we want the second column of i to be identical to the first colum of j or vice versa. 
                    if isequal(sort(sum(B(1:s,s+1:b+s,i))),sort(sum(B(1:s,s+1:b+s,j))))
                        B(:,l,i)=B(:,l,j);
                        B(l,:,i)=B(l,:,j);
                    else
                        ;
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
end
```

I understand that coder need something like "A:B" but my vector E here contains for example [7,11,13] and I cannot use something like "E(1,1):E(1,3)" because then I obvisouly get 7 8 9 10 11 12 13.

Any suggestions on how I could modify the code?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply do:

```
for ind = 1:length(E)
    i = E(ind);
    % ...
end
```